# How to add database to existing Aurora MySQL cluster using CDK?

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds, aws-cdk, amazon-aurora

We are switching from Terraform to CDK using TypeScript.  I was able to create a database cluster (Aurora MySQL) with 2 instances.  Converting the existing terraform used to create the cluster to CDK was straightforward, however, I'm having a hard time finding documentation on adding databases to the cluster using CDK.

Terraform uses a MySQL Provider to add database to a cluster:

```
# Configure the MySQL provider
provider "mysql" {
  endpoint = "my-database.example.com:3306"
  username = "app-user"
  password = "app-password"
}

# Create a Database
resource "mysql_database" "app" {
  name = "my_awesome_app"
}
```

I've searched around trying to find the equivalent CDK construct and process for adding a database to an existing cluster with no luck.  **Is this possible to do in CDK?**

--- update ---

Code to standup a cluster with 2 instances in cdk:

```
new rds.DatabaseCluster(
    this,
    `db-cluster`,
    {
        clusterIdentifier: `cluster`,
        credentials: rds.Credentials.fromSecret(...),
        engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraMysql({
            version: rds.AuroraMysqlEngineVersion.of(...)
        }),
        instances: 2,
        instanceProps: {
            vpc,
            securityGroups: [dbSecurityGroup],
            instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType(...)
        },
        subnetGroup,
        instanceIdentifierBase: 'instance-',
    })
```

Comment: CDK in which language? It's quite important to know 

Comment: Good catch, I updated the post.  I'm using TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please also show us some redacted code? How are you defining your `rds.DatabaseCluster` and current instances?

Comment: I updated the post with some code to stand up a cluster with 2 instances.

Comment: And now you want to create an instance standalone after this definition, that gets added to the cluster right? You don't want to define it as part of `instances` and `instanceProps`?

Comment: Or do you have a database instance that isn't managed by CDK and you want to add that to the cluster?

Comment: I'm creating a cluster with two database instances using CDK.  The cluster has an optional defaultDatabaseName prop when getting created, if not populated then no database with that name is created.  

I want to add more than 1 database to the cluster. 

What I'm trying to do the equivalent of what MySQL provider is used for in terraform: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/winebarrel/mysql/latest/docs

Comment: This is not available in CDK, you'll have to write a Custom Resource.